# Finding the geometrical relations in the following exercise

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm struggling to understand how in this exercise:
[image]

they get that $r_{F \ | \ \bar{O} } = \begin{bmatrix} L\cos^2(\phi) \\ r + L\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)
 \end{bmatrix}$

I have tried to split up the triangle DFP where P is the point that is on a line with D, so $\vec{P} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2r \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use $\times$ for ordinary multiplication in mathematics beyond middle school.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, I just find $*$ to be obscenely ugly!

Answer (score 1):

Hint…indicate the point where the dotted line through $D$ meets the $y$ axis as $X$.

Then $XD=L$ and $XF=L\cos\varphi$.

Can you finish it now?